# Index out of range convert date to string component

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, uisegmentedcontrol

I know this is a trivial error, but I can't figure it out and I am stuck.
I want to assign to a UISegmentedControl (having 6 segments) the current date in the first segment and the following 5 days dates in the next segments as in the picture below. To do this, I need to construct an array of string from date, but I get index out of range on this line `let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent-1]`

```
var stringDates = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


//for each segment, construct a string date with the currentDate() being first
    for i in 1...6 {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        let today = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        if i == 1 {
           let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.day,from: today)
             let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent-1]  
               let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: today)
                let monthSymbol = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols[month-1]

                   let dayMonthString = dayString + monthSymbol
                         stringDates.append(dayMonthString)
        } else {
           var components = DateComponents()
           components.weekday = i
            let nextDay = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: today)
              let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.day,from: nextDay!)
                let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent-1]

            let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: nextDay!)
              let monthSymbol = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols[month-1]
               let dayMonthString = dayString + monthSymbol
                  stringDates.append(dayMonthString)
         }          
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: If `dayComponent` is `0`, you get an index of `-1` in `shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.day` in `let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.day,from: today)`  use `.weekday` as shown below:

```
let today = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.weekday,from: today)
let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent - 1]  //Fri
```

Comment: Do you know why I get only current date when  `print("days of array \(stringDates)")` after the `for in` loop?

Comment: because you are using `today` everytime. You need to increase day into today.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for getting crash is that shortWeekdaySymbols[] can take only values from 0 to 6.

```
shortWeekdaySymbols[0] = sun
shortWeekdaySymbols[1] = mon
```

and so on.

```
let stringArray = [String]()
for value in 1 ..< 6 {

let today = Date()
let tomrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: value, to:today)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.weekday,from: tomrow!)
    let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: tomrow!)

    let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: tomrow!)
    let dayString = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[dayComponent - 1]
    let monthString = (dateFormatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols[month - 1])
    let FullDate =  String(day) + " " + monthString +  " " + dayString
    print(FullDate)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't find this explanation in the docs, but I am sure others will find it helpful

Comment: why is .weekday the 7th day today. Clearly today is Saturday, 6th day of the week. If you print `let dayComponent = Calendar.current.component(.weekday,from: Date())` It will print 7

Comment: @bibscy If it's Sunday  .weekday = 1, for Monday .weekday = 2,   ... and so on.. Therefore if it's Saturday .weekday = 7

Comment: Thanks, I initially thought it .weekday = 1 was Monday.